# Angular 5 - Add new line to a table, and make it editable

Tags: angular

I'm using a table to display the content of a collection, using `*ngFor = let item in collection`

On the bottom of the table, i have a button to add a new line, that redirects to my `addNewLine()` method.

In this method, I want to make the new row editable, and to make each cell represents an attribute from my model object.

I already added the new line,by making a `push(this.myModelObject)` but, I can't make it editable.

Thanks

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ngFor, you just display the content, so if you just push a new object in your collection, it can not do want you want.

You should add a form at the last line of table, and bind a empty object for the new object. After you successfully added this new record into your collection, just remove this new line of form. You can use `ngIf` to display the new line form.

[Update added example]

```
<form id="edit">
<table>
    <tr *ngFor.....  > display collection in tr </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="newRow">
        <th>Name: </th>
        <td>
            <input id="name" form="edit" type="text" ng-model="name" required>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button ng-click="newRow = true">New</button>
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

in the `save()` method, you just validate the input, push into the collection, and set `newRow` as false.