# How to give inline edit and delete button along with new button in prime ng for angular2 applications

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I have a page, which is of only one user thing.
But now i have to create a table and i need to fetch data, so that in the table i must have edit and delete button in inline. If i click on edit button then i must be able to edit the whole row, delete means entire row must be deleted.
And when i click on New  button, it must create me a new row with edit and delete actions.
i need to perform this using ng-prime itself.
So, can anyone help me with the links, or any demo.

Comment: check my answer for other post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396047/966698

Comment: you can use  `[editable]="true"`

Comment: ya but, i need to edit the whole row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `[editable]="true"`

From [Official Documentation reference](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/editable):

> Incell editing is enabled by setting editable property true both on
>   datatable and columns. Clicking a cell switches to edit mode and
>   hitting enter key or clicking another cell switches it back to view
>   mode.

**Component:**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  data: any = [];
  delRow;

  editRow(row) {
        this.data.filter(row => row.isEditable).map(r => { r.isEditable = false; return r })
    row.isEditable = true;
  }

  save(row){
    row.isEditable = false
  }

  addNew(){
    this.data.push({
      name: '',
      value: ''
    })
  }

  delete(row){
      console.log(row);
      this.delRow = this.data.indexOf(row);
      this.data.splice(this.delRow,1);
      console.log(this.data);

  }

  getData() {    
    this.data = [
      {name: "Name1", value: "value1"},
      {name: "Name2", value: "value2"},
      {name: "Name3", value: "value3"},
      {name: "Name4", value: "value4"}
      ];
      this.data.map(row => {      
        row.isEditable = false;        
      });    

  };


}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <button (click)="getData()">Load Data</button>
<button (click)="addNew()">Add New</button>

<p-dataTable [immutable]="false" [value]="data" [editable]="true">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <div *ngIf="!row.isEditable">{{row.name}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="row.isEditable">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="row.name">
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="value" header="Value">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <div *ngIf="!row.isEditable">{{row.value}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="row.isEditable">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="row.value">
        </div>
    </ng-template></p-column>    

    <p-column field="" header="" [style]="{'text-align':'center'}">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <button (click)="editRow(row)">Edit</button>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="" header="" [style]="{'text-align':'center'}">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <button (click)="save(row)">Save</button>
      </ng-template>

    </p-column>
     <p-column field="" header="" [style]="{'text-align':'center'}">
      <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <button (click)="delete(row)">Delete</button>
      </ng-template>


    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

[**Here is a WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xncw9a)